# Latex snippet associate with Rnw mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, sweave, yasnippet

I would like to have my yasnippets for Latex mode to be available for .Rnw files. How to go about this? Also, it would be nice to have R snippets available as well.

**EDIT:**
I found out the real problem is that in .Rnw the `TAB` key is bound not to yasnippets. Does anyone know how to tackle this problem not messing up anything? (it is bound to `noweb-indent-line`)

Comment: read the doc of yas-parents, http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/snippet-organization.html#id5 , its possible and trivial\

Comment: @kindahero I suppose that would work, except that the real problem lies with the .Rnw mode.

Comment: what is that "real" problem? may be ask in a different question.? and if you have got the solution to this question, you could contribute to the answer.

Comment: reread the edit/temporary solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got fed up not being able to change the keymap of `noweb-minor-mode-map`, `ess-noweb-mode-map`, `local-set-key` and whatever that I gave up and just deleted the code from ess-indent and replaced it by (`yas-expand`)